# Using best_fields with an "and" operator and phrase in multi_match search returns 0 results

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

I have forum posts indexed in ElasticSearch with title and body as fields.

I have a post with "Body text phrase" in the body and "Title of the thread" as the title. When I do the following query it doesn't return any results but if I take the "operator":"and" it works fine. Why is this happening?

```
"query": {
  "bool": {
   "must": [
    {
     "multi_match": {
      "query": "Body text phrase",
      "type": "phrase",
      "fields": [
       "body",
       "title"
      ]
     }
    },
    {
     "multi_match": {
      "query": "Title of the thread",
      "type": "best_fields",
      "fields": [
       "body",
       "title"
      ],
      "operator":"and"
     }
    }
   ]
  }
 }
```

Comment: Try to [explain](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-explain.html) your query and check the lucene query that produces your dsl, this will help you to understand what's going wrong.

Comment: Hm, I tried it out with one doc, and your query. Seems to be working fine for me. If I remove the operator it keeps working. So maybe you have a more specific mapping? Can you try it with a clean index and maybe post the command that you used to create the index as well?

Comment: @jordivador using explain doesn't really help me because there's no results.

Comment: @JettroCoenradie They are indexed like this: {"_index":"forum","_type":"post","_id":20001035} with _id as the post.id from the database.

Comment: @HugoMarques Is not for check results, explain it's for check the lucene syntax of query that you're doing . This could help you to understand the difference between use "operator" or not in multi_match query.

Comment: @jordivador I know. But it only explains the query if there are any results or am I using incorrectly?

Comment: Yes, you're right. But in other hand, if you have some id of any doc from your index you could use: 

```
curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/your_index/your_type/id/_explain' -d '{your_query}'
```

The result, will not have any score/match information but you'll be able to check lucene syntax of your query.

Comment: Thanks @jordivador. That really helped understanding it better.